# How can I display shared preference values in a list?

Tags: android

I am using this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefName;
prefName = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);

CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(packageInfo.packageName,    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));

prefName.edit().putBoolean((String) c, false).commit();
```

Now i want to display prefName in a list, to display list I am using this code:

```
 ProcessList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
 ProcessList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,ARRAYLIST) );
 ProcessList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

How to convert the 'prefName' to array list so that I can display it in a list.

Comment: you shouldn't cast 'c' to string and then add it to your preferences as a boolean. If you want it as a string, use Editor.putString(), if not, then convert c to boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not convert it directly. You extract the values you need, one by one, and put them in a list which you then feed to the adapter.